# o365 management api product specific schema

Tags: api, office365

I'm using the o365 management api to get Teams data but the result I'm getting is only related to the common schema. How do I get the product specific data as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#microsoft-teams-schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the MS Teams activity if you start a subscription with `contentType = Audit.General` ([Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#working-with-the-office-365-management-activity-api)).

I got the activity of MS Teams which `Operation` is `ChannelSettingChanged` and `Workload` is `MicrosoftTeams` via the [List available content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#list-available-content).

```
[{'ChannelGuid': <cguid>,
  'ChannelName': 'new test',
  'ChannelType': 'Standard',
  'CreationTime': '2020-06-30T02:32:23',
  'Id': <id>,
  'Name': 'Channel name',
  'NewValue': 'new test',
  'OldValue': 'old test',
  'Operation': 'ChannelSettingChanged',
  'OrganizationId': <oid>,
  'RecordType': 25,
  'TeamGuid': <tid>,
  'TeamName': <tname>,
  'UserId': <uid>,
  'UserKey': <ukey>,
  'UserType': 0,
  'Version': 1,
  'Workload': 'MicrosoftTeams'}]
```